# Authorization Asp.net web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-config, roles

I have an application that has a backoffice.
This backoffice was isolated with the use of roles like this:

```
<location path="backoffice">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="admin"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

But now we have another type of role that needs access. The companyadmin role.

Can I just say?:

```
 <location path="backoffice">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="admin,companyadmin"/>
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, exactly so (assuming you properly authenticated your users, and set their roles accordingly).

Check the MSDN article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/8d82143t(v=vs.71)

Comment: It may be important to note that order does matter. According to the docs, it will check one rule at a time in short-circuit fashion. i.e., if the first rule is a "deny all," then the resource will be denied. If the user passes by the first rule with an allow, then access is granted.

Answer (score 4):

yes, you can add n roles like that.

If you prefer, you can also:

```
<allow roles="admin"/>
<allow roles="admin1"/>
<deny users="*"/>
```

Comment: what the hell is going on with that grammar?

Comment: @mbillard He's saying 'N' number of roles, meaning as many as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, roles, users and verbs takes comma separated values.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsd09b0(VS.80).aspx)