# set permission to specific folder with web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, authorization, config

Multi site is on same physical path.

How could I set permission for two domain like: domain1.com,domain2.com to access to specific folder.

Note: I put the config file inside of specific folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
          <allow roles="domain1.com/domain2.com" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authorization Asp.net web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642515/authorization-asp-net-web-config) (It leads to roles="comma-separated list of roles".)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Could you please explain where should I add "domain1.com"? The link doesn't mention that.

Comment: Use a comma, not a slash, to separate the roles: `<allow roles="domain1.com,domain2.com" />`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton access denied. Even I try to use <allow roles="domain1.com" /> and it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps I need some clarification. Do you mean that you want requests from web servers with the hostname "domain1.com" or "domain2.com" to be able to access resources in that specific directory? Or do you mean clients (browsers) which are loading pages from "domain1.com" or "domain2.com" to be able to access those resources?

Comment: Just to check, have you assigned roles to the users?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Multi site like "domain1.com" and "domain2.com" shows data from one root. There is many folders on the root and I want to let client to access to each folder by checking url. So  "domain3.com" can't access to what "domain2.com" able to to. This is why I put web.config inside each folder for checking it's access or not.

Comment: Do the users log in to each site separately?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, they didn't login.

Comment: If there is no login, then why is there a restriction on what they can access? If there is, for example, a list of items they see when they are logged in to one of the sites, then you could filter the list to be displayed by checking the `Request.Url.Host` property. Docs: [HttpRequest.Url Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.url), [Uri.Host Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.host).

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's a project who gave a service to customers. Our customers have their own domain, So I try to handle all domains on one root. Each customers has images/videos ... domain1.com should shows only data of his account. I able to use random string like "3625-b123-4e38-882b-64a1f689" for addressing, but on case one user share his link, other customer able to see that image on their domain. It can be awful if someone find our bug.

Comment: That does help to clarify it. What you *could* do is check every request to compare the host name to some prepared list of allowed directories. You could base it on the code shown at [Authorize HttpModule (with Session)](https://martinwilley.com/net/code/AuthorizeModule.html), except that you don't need the session part. But that would be rather a lot for me to make into an answer.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for sharing your time. I know it's hard to solve. Again thanks dear Andrew